# Embed.ly and PHP... round 2

Tags: php, html, embed, wamp

Apparently my last question was too vague even though it was pretty straightforward.

I'm trying to use Embed.ly's API to embed some stuff, for example, some of the stuff shown here. 
https://github.com/embedly/embedly-php/blob/master/README.rst

I have the entire Embedly.php source file in my working directory.

However, when I have the following in my header file:

```
<?php
        //require_once('Embedly/src/Embedly/Embedly.php');  // if using pear
        require_once('./Embedly.php');  // if using source

        $api = new Embedly\Embedly(array('user_agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible;     mytestapp/1.0)'));
?>
```

And the following in my main page:

```
<?php
    $objs = $api->oembed(array(
    'urls' => array(
    'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sPbJ4Z5D-n4&feature=topvideos',
    'http://twitpic.com/3yr7hk'
)
));
    ?>
```

I get the following error:

( ! ) Fatal error: Call to undefined function Embedly\curl_init() in C:\wamp\www\Embedly.php on line 259

Comment: Check your php.ini or phpinfo() if curl is enabled.

Comment: I'm using WAMP and I cannot find anything about curl in any of those files. Maybe I'm looking in the wrong place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like curl isn't installed or enabled.

If you're on you own server (assuming something similar to ubuntu server), a simple `sudo apt-get install php5-curl` should solve it.

Otherwise, you may have to contact your hosting provider.

Comment: The W in wamp means windows, last time I checked.

Comment: @Tory- Arvin was talking to Ragnar123.

Answer (score 0):

Got this from a [forum](http://www.dibugs.com/comment/1011/Re-CURL-enabling-WAMP) and it seems legit:

1. Close WAMP (if running)
2. Navigate to WAMP\bin\php(your version of php)\
3. Edit php.ini
4. Search for curl, uncomment extension=php_curl.dll
5. Navigate to WAMP\bin\Apache(your version of apache)\bin\
6. Edit php.ini
7. Search for curl, uncomment the line/remove the #, extension=php_curl.dll
8. Save the files
9. Restart WAMP

Comment: The error is now gone, but now absolutely nothing shows up. Nothing embedded.

Comment: @Tory The tutorial on github includes a part where the object is outputted using `print_r($objs);` maybe you forgot that?

Comment: @Tory @Arvin I'm pretty sure that if the error is gone, then this fixed your problem.  You now have a NEW problem where your code isn't doing what you expect it to.  I would try to debug for as long as possible and then come back with a new question relating exclusively to your code, as these are no doubt two different issues.